# display calendar (date picker) in html page

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me with this code. Is there any problem? Because I'm not able to display the calendar when I'm running it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="CSS/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Holder"></div>
    <div id="Datepicker1"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("#Datepicker1").datepicker({
          numberOfMonths:3
        }); 
      });

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm assuming the first line of your console will tell you everything you need to know. You're not including jQuery *or* jQuery UI. In the future, please spend a little while doing some research and walking through the basic debugging procedures, like checking console and reviewing the plugin documentation. You can narrow down your issue by leaps and bounds, and if you can't solve it on your own from there, searching for answers to a specific error message will always yield more helpful results.

Comment: Look at ***View Source*** of a demo https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Also, your HTML closing tags are incorrect. You close the "Datepicker1" element twice and don't close the body, the script, or the html.

Comment: @NShumway Believe OP had some issues with the code markdown in their question (I've edited to fix), but you're still correct in regards to the double `</div>` tag as well as the missing `</script>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you haven't included jQuery or jQuery UI, and your HTML closing tags are incorrect. If you view the source of the demo on the jqueryui site, you will find the code is a little different you yours.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

To implement this into your code, it would be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="CSS/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="holder"></div>
    <div id="datepicker1"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
          numberOfMonths:3
        }); 
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just need to change the id for the text input to correct id (datepicker1) and remove the line <div id="datepicker1"></div> if you want to show only when you click inside the text box.

Comment: Any idea to put onclick event to call another php page when you click on the date?

Comment: If you want to get the date as variable to do some query just place it inside form tag then put some if statement to check $_POST['datefilter'] then do some database query according the parsed date.

<div id="holder">Filter by date:</div>
<form method="post" action="filter.php">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datefilter"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          numberOfMonths:1
        }); 
      });
    </script>
<button class="btn" type="submit" name="search" >Filter</button>    
</form>

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jQuery and jQuery UI (I changed a few things in your markup as well):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- <link> doesn't need a closing tag -->
    <link href="CSS/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- include the jQuery UI style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <!-- include jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <!-- include jQuery UI -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Datepicker1"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("#Datepicker1").datepicker({
         numberOfMonths: 3
        }); 
      });
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```